# Does NetCDF4excel provide packed or unpacked values?

Tags: excel, netcdf

I'm using the [NetCDF4excel](http://netcdf4excel.github.io/) tool to work on files from the ERA Interim database. I'm wondering whether I should adjust the values of the variables produced by the tool using each variable's "scale_factor" and "add_offset", or whether the tool does this for you.

I've tried:

- Going through the documentation, and this is not clear.
- Adjusting the values provided and comparing them with the unconverted ones
  doesn't help either because in both cases you obtain feasible values
  (the difference for temperatures, for example, is within 10C).
- Another possibility would be to check whether missing values are filled with the missing value code (in this case -32767) or whether they are in fact converted to missing, but since this is reanalysis data there are no missing values.

Comment: Can you query values using `ncview` to compare?

Comment: Hi @RichardLaw, I'm not sure that function is included in the NetCDF4excel package I'm working with. Could you explain a bit more what you mean? Thanks!

Comment: [`ncview`](http://meteora.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncview_home_page.html) is a separate application for viewing NetCDF datasets. I suggest using that to validate the values you're being presented with in Excel, in order to determine if offsets are applied or not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm on a PC and the procedure to run ncview on a non-Unix system seem a bit out of my reach. I've checked the values by constructing both adjusted and unadjusted ones, and plotting them against other sources of the same data and it seems like the excel tool provides the unpacked data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I constructed two possible versions of my variables of interest, one assuming that the tool was returning "unpacked" values, and one assuming they were still "packed" and needed adjustment. I plotted them against each other and against another source and it seems like the tool actually returns *unpacked* values. No rescaling or offsets should be required.